# How to unscrew freewheel sprockets with 9 broken spokes

Tags: repair, freewheel, spokes

A friend of mine has this problem. I haven't seen the wheel, but I suppose that the broken spokes are in one "area". It's a 27 inch wheel.

Is there any tool that can hold hub tight enough to use a freewheel wrench?

Comment: I've generally found that it's possible to find a place on the rim where there's enough spokes to hold it and undo the freewheel. If not, I'd try a length of rope looped round the rim and hub a few times to effectively replace the spokes, then pull on the rope. It's easy to get to the point where you've spent more time than the wheel is worth, though. If you just want the freewheel, cut the rest of the spokes and put the hub in a vice.

Comment: Don't cut the spokes. Put the thing in a vise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless its a super low spoke count wheel (16 or 20) then it should have 32 or 36 spokes.  9 broken ones is totally unrideable, but the remaining spokes should be okay to get the freewheel off with a vise and a freewheel tool.

Depending on what killed 9 spokes, the rim may be unusable, and at some point your wallet is better off with a new replacement wheel.

Comment: If the rim was damaged, your face will be better off than attempting to ride the repaired wheel, as well.

Answer (score 4):

This one is way easy. Use a pneumatic impact wrench.  There is very little torque transmitted. Bruuupppp and its off. I use this a lot with my single speed spin on cassette with the torque from Hades. When I did this manually, I needed a six foot breaker with wheel tied down. Impact hammer is awesome.

[image]

No vise. No marks on part. I would just hold hub carefully with work gloves.  Heck, bring it by my house, we'll have it off in 30 seconds.

Comment: Very nice idea!

Comment: I would really like to mark this as an answer, but we didn't checked if this worked. My friend is going to buy new wheel and dispose broken, so Criggie answer is what we acually did.